# SQL grouped running sum

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have some data like this

```
data = [("1","1"), ("1","1"), ("1","1"), ("2","1"), ("2","1"), ("3","1"), ("3","1"), ("4","1"),]

df =spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=["id","imp"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

+---+---+
| id|imp|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  1|
|  3|  1|
|  3|  1|
|  4|  1|
+---+---+
```

I want the count of IDs grouped by ID, it's running sum and total sum. This is the code I'm using

```
query = """
    select id,
           count(id) as count,
           sum(count(id)) over (order by count(id) desc) as running_sum,
           sum(count(id)) over () as total_sum
           from df
           group by id
           order by count desc
    """


spark.sql(query).show()
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
| id|count|running_sum|total_sum|
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
|  1|    3|          3|        8|
|  2|    2|          7|        8|
|  3|    2|          7|        8|
|  4|    1|          8|        8|
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
```

The problem is with the `running_sum` column. For some reason it automatically groups the count 2 while summing and shows 7 for both ID 2 and 3.

This is the result I'm expecting

```
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
| id|count|running_sum|total_sum|
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
|  1|    3|          3|        8|
|  2|    2|          5|        8|
|  3|    2|          7|        8|
|  4|    1|          8|        8|
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the running sum in an outer query.

```py
spark.sql('''
    select *, 
        sum(cnt) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as run_sum,
        sum(cnt) over (partition by '1') as tot_sum
    from (
        select id, count(id) as cnt
        from data_tbl
        group by id)
    '''). \
    show()

# +---+---+-------+-------+
# | id|cnt|run_sum|tot_sum|
# +---+---+-------+-------+
# |  1|  3|      3|      8|
# |  2|  2|      5|      8|
# |  3|  2|      7|      8|
# |  4|  1|      8|      8|
# +---+---+-------+-------+
```

Using dataframe API

```py
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('id'). \
    agg(func.count('id').alias('cnt')). \
    withColumn('run_sum', 
               func.sum('cnt').over(wd.partitionBy().orderBy('id').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
               ). \
    withColumn('tot_sum', func.sum('cnt').over(wd.partitionBy())). \
    show()

# +---+---+-------+-------+
# | id|cnt|run_sum|tot_sum|
# +---+---+-------+-------+
# |  1|  3|      3|      8|
# |  2|  2|      5|      8|
# |  3|  2|      7|      8|
# |  4|  1|      8|      8|
# +---+---+-------+-------+
```